# Ways of storing large constants in a smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have to implement a **smart contract** using large constants (*about 30kb*).

> I read that there is a limit of ***24kb*** on `Solidity`'s contract size.

So I'm wondering if there is a nice way of circumventing this, because
I know I can write a function that stores those constants and call it right after the contract's deployment.

> Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Hmm, the 24Kb limit on Contract size should refer to the size of its code. Not the storage size of its variables. Did you maybe try to test this on your local network? (Did your contract deployment actually fail?)

Comment: Not yet. There will be a major difference in the work I have to do depending on the answer to this question, so I'm trying to find out if there is a definite answer beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so in short, `2^261` bytes is the **theoretical** limit on how much data you can store in smartContract. So there is no way you will ever fill that up.

However, the max size of the SmartContract (its code) is only up to `24Kb` (on most EVM networks). Therefore your large constants `30Kb` should not be an issue from that perspective. Because they don't increase the size of the `code` only `storage`.

For example: These two arrays have very different storage sizes `(10 << 1000)`, but their **code size** difference is negligible.

```
unit[10] smallArray;

unit[1000] bigArray;
```

But what **might** be an issue for you is the `blockGasLimit` (The maximum amount of data/gas you can write/spend for a single block).

So if your transaction goes over the blockchain's `blockGasLimit` you will not be able to deploy the contract. Considering contract deployment is also just a big transaction.

In short. I don't believe large contact variables will be an issue. Rather it will be the size of the transaction that might limit you. And that is why you will need to test it locally first.